# imagick conversion from svg to png returns black colored image

Tags: imagick

i have a svg image that is to be converted to png/jpeg, i can convert it to png/jpg but the image created is changed to black from green (svg image). Any idea whats wrong it?

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));
$im->readimage('ace-logo.svg');//Image with transparent background
$im->setImageFormat("png32");
$im->writeimage('ace-logo-converted.png');
```

we have PHP Version 7.2.11 and ImageMagick 6.9.7-4.

I actually use the same codes above in our older version of php and imagemagick and it is working. (PHP Version 5.6.36 and ImageMagick 6.7.7-10).

Any idea what wrong? is there anything we missed out in our php7 version?

[image output becomes black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AZS7.png)

the svg file i use --> [svg file](https://svgshare.com/i/9G8.svg)

Comment: There could be a bug in ImageMagick 6.9.7.4. Can you post your SVG file so we can test with it in your version of ImageMagick and in the current one. Or try upgrading ImageMagick. The current version is 6.9.10.14. Also check that your version of libpng is current. It could have a bug with whatever version you are using.

Comment: i edited the post and added a link to the svg i used. hope you can help.. anyway , we try also to update to 6.9.10.14. hopefully it will fix it.

Comment: The link to your SVG file is not accessible. "
Error
 
Over Quota

This application is temporarily over its serving quota. Please try again later."

Comment: Try replacing `$im->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));` with `$im->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel("rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0)"));`